# Meshes pushed other side when sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I'm new to sculpting, and i've noticed that the mesh is pushed when sculpting and not compressed.

So for exemple if I have a wall, and if I dig some holes with a brush on one face for exemple, at a certain point I will be able so see all the mesh going outside behind the wall at the opposite face..

[image]

So i wanted to know if there is a way to avoid this ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Maybe first check if the *Front Faces Only* option of the brush is enabled:

[image]

You can also use the *Mask* brush. Paint on the face that you don't want to deform. To erase the whole mask, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. To erase some parts, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you paint:

[image]

Then sculpt, the maskded area won't be affected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !!